# Validate combination of dice

Tags: java, android, algorithm, validation, dice

I am buidling an app called Thirty Throws in Android and I am completely stuck 
with my validation. 
In Thirty Throws you have the scores 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 6 dice.
Each turn consists of 3 throws and the user can choose the dice he wish to keep between every throw. 
Example say that the user has thrown 4,4,3,5,1,5 then he can choose the score 11 because 4 + 4 +3 = 11 and 5 + 1 + 5 = 11 or if the user has thrown 2,2,2 he can choose 6.

I'm struggling with validating the score. The code I have at the moment manage to validate most. What am I missing?

I've been looking at some recursive solution here but they seem no to be what I am looking for since I have to return a boolean.

```
public static boolean isValidResult(ArrayList<Integer> score, int selectedPoints)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> notReadyNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i: score) {
        if (i == selectedPoints) {
            continue;
        }

        if (CalcSum(notReadyNumbers) + i == selectedPoints) {
            notReadyNumbers.clear();
        } else {
            boolean isDone = false;
            if (notReadyNumbers.size() > 0) {
                for (int z: notReadyNumbers) {
                    if (z + i == selectedPoints) {
                        isDone = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isDone) {
                notReadyNumbers.clear();
            } else {
                notReadyNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return notReadyNumbers.size() == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe more about this method? I am bit confused what you are trying to do inside of this method.

Comment: yes, ArrayList<Integer> score consists of the choosen dice and selectedPoints is the score the user has choosen.
First I am looping score. If the number from score match selectedPoints I am moving to the next number.
If the number don't match I am adding the number to notReadyNumbers.

Comment: So you mean that score = [4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]. And what is selectedPoints?

Comment: According to your example 11 is the selectedPoints?

Comment: If CalcSum + i don't match I am looking if the notReadyNumbers is empty, if it's not I am looping it to controll if any of the number in the list + i matched selectedPoints - if it does I am removing all elements in notReadyNumbers.

In case nothing matches I am adding the element in the list notReadyNumbers.

And finally I return true if notReadyNumbers is 0, because then all integers have succesfully been summed.

The problem is that I am not iterating through all possible results.  

If the number don't match I am adding the number to notReadyNumbers.

Comment: selectedPoints is the type of score the user has choosen. It can be 4-12.
score is the results from throwing the dice. It can hold between one to six integers.

Example, a user has thrown 6, 3, 3 the score will hold these values and the user choose 6 as the type of score he would like to have.

Comment: You are trying if sum of two numbers is equal to your selectedPoints. Why every time two numbers? Why not three or four?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Please describe a little more what you want to check in this function with example.

Comment: Alright, the user has thrown all six dices and has the score  on the dice is 1,4,4,5,3,5.
Then the user selects the score type 11. 
I would like with the function to validate that all of the dice can sum up to 11 in one way or the other. Each dice can only be counted on time. Example 5 + 5 + 1 = 11 and 4 + 4 + 3 = 11. 
As it is right now it can't validate this example.

Comment: Great! I think I have got it. But two more example for more understanding. If scores are 5,3,1,4,3,6 then what will you want to return? true/false?
If 5,3,1,4,4,6 what will be returned?

Comment: it depends which selectedPoints the user is going for.  If scores are 5,3,1,4,3,6 and the user goes for 6 it should return false because 5 + 1 = 6, 3 + 3 = 6, 6 = 6 but 4 != 6. If the user instead chooses to omit the 4 and then has the result 5,3,1,3,6 it should return true if selectedPoints are 6.

I am doing a first check before this function to make sure the there is no rest divison. CalcCum(sumOfAllDice) % selectedPoints = 0

Comment: Good. So you want to pick some numbers from scores list whose sum is equal to selectedPoints. And these some numbers may be consist of one number, or two numbers, or three numbers, or four numbers or five numbers or six numbers. Am I right?

Comment: Yes,  that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take all possible numbers from any position. So in order to take all possible result you may use permutation of these numbers to serialise the numbers. Another way is to use **bit-masking** with **recursion**.
Here is a solution of your problem. (Based on **bit-masking** and **recursion**).

```
public static boolean isValidResult(ArrayList<Integer> score, int selectedPoints)
{
    return canMakeValid(score, selectedPoints, 0, 0); // first 0 is for masking, second 0 is for summation.
}

public static boolean canMakeValid(ArrayList<Integer> score, int selectedPoints, int mask, int sum) 
{
    if(sum > selectedPoints) return false;
    sum %= selectedPoints;
    int sz = score.size();
    if(mask == ((1<<sz)-1)) {
        if(sum == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
    boolean ret = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if((mask&(1<<i)) == 0) {
            ret = ret | canMakeValid(score, selectedPoints, mask | (1<<i), sum + score.get(i));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You can learn about bit-masking from this link: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/a-small-tutorial-on-bitmasking/11811/3

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are some recursive solutions.

```
public static boolean isValidResult(List<Integer> score, int selectedPoints) {
    score.sort();
    return isValidResultRec(score, selectedPoints, 0);
}

/**
 * @param scoreI the first position to consider to add or not add.
 */
private static boolean isValidResultRec(List<Integer> score, int selectedPoints, int scoreI) {
    while (!score.isEmpty() && scoreI < score.size()) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(score, selectedPoints);
        if (index >= 0) {
           return true;
        }
        // Now ~index is the insert position;
        // i >= ~index are values > selectedPoints.
        score = score.subList(~index, score.size());
        for (int i = scoreI; i < ~index; ++i) {
            int value = score[i]; // value < selectedPoints.
            score.remove(i); // Do step.
            if (isValidResultRec(score, selectedPoints - value, scoreI + 1) {
                return true;
            }
            score.add(i, value); // Undo step.
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here *sorting* is used; using decreasing order, `Comparator.reversed()`, or a `for --i` would take larger steps.

The recursion should either add the i<sup>th</sup> dice value or not.

The code here can be written nicer.